# Module not found in the module list of Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

i am trying to create a module but mymodule is not showing up in the module list and i have done some following things.

1.) In the modules directory in the root directory of prestashop there is mymodcomments/mymodcomments.php.
 the code in this is

```
<?php

class MyModComments extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodcomments';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '0.1';
        $this->author = 'coold';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l('My Module of product comments');
        $this->description = $this->l('With this module, your customers will be able to grade and comments your products.');
    }
}

?>
```

I understood this code clearly, but could not see my module in the module list of back office.

**My another question is:**
I am using windows, can there be any file permission while working with prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes there are problems when module class and module name uses different uppercase or lowercase.

Try defining this:

```
class mymodcomments extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodcomments';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '0.1';
        $this->author = 'coold';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l('My Module of product comments');
        $this->description = $this->l('With this module, ....');
    }
}
```

It's not elegant but could do the trick.

About capital letters problem, is not reported on prestashop. 95% of installations works fine but by unknown reasons some prestashop installations can't face problems by these differences.

Regards